# Почему std::regex_search так работает?

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, std-regex

Ожидаю, что вызов std::regex_search(..) должен сохранить в std::smatch все найденные результаты поиска. Однако находит только одно совпадение. Не могу понять, в чем причина. Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "regex"

int main(void)
{
    const std::string data("123 78");

    const std::regex regex("[0-9]+");
    std::smatch match;

    const bool res = std::regex_search(data, match, regex);

    std::cout << "res            = " << (res ? "true" : "false") << std::endl;
    std::cout << "match.size()   = " << match.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "match[0].str() = " << match[0].str() << std::endl; 
    std::cout << "match[1].str() = " << match[1].str() << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод

```
res            = true
match.size()   = 1
match[0].str() = 123
match[1].str() =
```

Comment: Попробуйте так: https://ideone.com/ZAw482

Comment: Работает. Большое спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Понимаете, эта функция ищет первое же вхождение, а все эти `match[1]` и прочие - на случай наличия *групп*:

```
const std::string data("123 78");

const std::regex regex("([0-9])([0-9]+)");
std::smatch match;

const bool res = std::regex_search(data, match, regex);

std::cout << "res            = " << (res ? "true" : "false") << std::endl;
std::cout << "match.size()   = " << match.size() << std::endl;
std::cout << "match[0].str() = " << match[0].str() << std::endl; 
std::cout << "match[1].str() = " << match[1].str() << std::endl;
std::cout << "match[2].str() = " << match[2].str() << std::endl;
```

Смотрите - теперь есть две группы - первый символ, остальные. Поэтому в `match[0]` вы получаете всю подстроку, а в `match[1]` и `match[2]` - подстроки, соответствующие группам.

То, что вы хотите - делается с помощью `sregex_iterator`:

```
int main()
{
    const std::string data("123 78");
 
    const std::regex rg("[0-9]+");
 
    auto begin = std::sregex_iterator(data.begin(), data.end(), rg),
        end = std::sregex_iterator();
 
    for(auto i = begin; i != end; ++i)
    {
        std::smatch match = *i;
        std::cout << match.str() << std::endl;
    }
}
```